# optimization with constraint

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods

The topic we are giving is optimization with restrictions. So, the exercise they gave me is the following:

minimize $f(x,y,z)=x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}$

subject to the following restrictions: $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}-5=0$ and $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}-2x-3=0$.

I proceed to use the lagrange multiplier, so I have the following system of equations:

$(Ec.1)$  $2x-\lambda(2x)-\mu(2x-2)=0$

$(Ec.2)$  $2y-\lambda(2y)-\mu(2y)=0$

$(Ec.3)$  $2z-\lambda(2z)-\mu(2z)=0$

$(Ec.4)$  $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}-5=0$

$(Ec.5)$  $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}-2x-3=0$

solving this system in matlab get the following results $x=\lambda=1$, $y=z=1.4142$, $\mu={-7.2176e^{-11}}$

Now I must see the optimality condition but I don't know how to proceed, someone please help me on how I can finish the exercise

Comment: This seems a bit strange. You are told to minimize $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$ given that $x^2+y^2+z^2=5$, ok, so the minimum is $5$. Then we are told that $5-2x-3=0$ so it must be the case that $x=1$. So $y^2+z^2=4$. Looks like the solutions would consist of the points $(1,y,z)$ such that $y^2+z^2=4$.

Comment: what do you mean by 'I must see the optimality condition'? What optimality condition?

Answer (score 1):

As it was mentioned in the comments, since one of the constraints sets the value of the objective function to $5$, you only have two possibilities:

1. The feasible set is empty and there is no solution, i.e. the two restrictions are incompatible (This is not the case).
2. The objective function is constant over the feasible set and the minimum an maximum are both 5.

If you want to ignore this and just look at the system you wrote:

1. The last two equations yield directly $x = 1$, $y^2+ z^2 = 4$.
2. Substituting $x=1$ in the first equation you get $\lambda = 1$.
3. Equations (2),(3) then give you $\mu y = 0$ and $\mu z = 0$

So, taking $\mu = 0$, you get as a solution every point such that $x = 1$ and $y^2+z^2=4$. If $\mu \ne 0$, then $z = y = 0$, which is impossible.

Finally, each point in the feasible set is a critical point of the Lagrangian... Since the feasible set is compact, and the objective function in continuous, there will be a minimum and maximum over the set. Additionally, considerations on the Jacobian matrix of the restricitons guarantee that the min/max are critical points of the Lagrangian. But the value of $f$ over all those critical points is the same, and we are done.

You may also use criteria on the "bordered Hessian" to get to the same conclusion.